# Load partial view on button click after navigation to another page in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I made one partial view and calling it from button inside Layout.

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function () {
                $('#btnSubmit').click(function (e) {
                    var url1 = "@Url.Action("CreateCalendar", "AdminDashboard", new { area = "Admin" })";

                    $.get(url1, function (result) {
                        $("#partialCalDiv").html("");
                        $("#partialCalDiv").html(result);
                    });
                    $("#partialCalDiv").slideToggle("slow");
                });
            });
</script>
```

and in main body

```
<button id="btnSubmit" type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="height:40px;width:50px;"> </button>

                <div id="partialCalDiv" style="height:510px;width:810px;z-index:1006; margin:0 auto">

                </div>
```

It is working fine. 
But when I go to another page from here I click again on button to load that partial view, it is not hitting the controller/view.

What I am doing wrong here?

Comment: What do you mean by you "go to another page from here"? Does the new page have a `partialCalDiv`?

Comment: where you have placed your partial view ? it is in your master layout ?

Comment: Yes it is in layout page.

Answer (score 0):

It may be because the event binding to button is lost when you change the page. You can try this

```
<script>
     $(document).ready(function () {
                $(document).on('click', '#btnSubmit', function (e) {
                    var url1 = "@Url.Action("CreateCalendar", "AdminDashboard", new { area = "Admin" })";

                    $.get(url1, function (result) {
                        $("#partialCalDiv").html("");
                        $("#partialCalDiv").html(result);
                    });
                    $("#partialCalDiv").slideToggle("slow");
                });
            });
</script>
```